# Minimum software to broadcast a Bitcoin transaction on a resource constrained environment

Tags: transactions

What is the minimum software I would need to broadcast a Bitcoin transaction without using an external service like bitcoin.info?

- I have a signed transaction that I just want to spit into the
  blockchain preferably through the command line.
- Preferably without having to fully install Bitcoin core.
- Preferably not using a browser.
- I don't have the resources to run a full node.
- I have a very limited bandwidth, think of it from an IoT perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least resource demanding method I can think of is to use cURL.
The code snippet below will broadcast using https://blockchain.info/pushtx

```
curl -X POST -d tx='your raw transaction in hex format' https://blockchain.info/pushtx
```

Example usage:

```
curl -X POST -d tx=0100000001492d631b86db96ab8b2d50bea0bec53ebde8eda603bdae6441289de454f89cd8010000006b483045022100e21e298f1ce99ade77502955b2bfa1acf1ada40a30e7b3a8ed86ae08bf9b7566022001a9b43a24abdb1b90eac434619f0a49ca2c8ec4152576ac8df0b63de43e2e68012102ed8725a530d72af0cbbaa96b1936042952ae73b78221edc596ea53c9a1c7a2b2ffffffff0210270000000000001976a914a0e6ca5444e4d8b7c80f70237f332320387f18c788ac250e0000000000001976a914ff4b370002146338c95827273de755e0eb8574cb88ac00000000 https://blockchain.info/pushtx
```

Otherwise I would recommend using a SPV wallet like Electrum, it is both lightweight and not resource-demanding at all.

If you are looking for the highest level of granularity/control, [Bitcoins the hard way: Using the raw Bitcoin protocol](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html) might interest you.

Comment: what would be the url to post to the testnet?